Is it appropriate to explain why you think downvoters are missing something?
Question: Is there a way to invert a filter in Turbo?
I made an edit that explains why the downvoters (-3 right now and it got downvoted fast) seem to be missing something.
Someone tried to rollback that edit.
Is it considered inappropriate to explain in a question why you think the downvoters are missing something?

You mean the last edit that adds "I have clearly explained why the docs and the existing answers don't actually answer my question, the downvoters are apparently not reading the question properly."? That doesn't look like an explanation, more like a rant... I don't see how that adds anything useful to the question.

Social & meta commentary are noise & don't belong in posts. Addressing voting is noise in posts & comments. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/266284 PS Please don't yell.

Only one revision has been rolled back by somebody other than you. And I can hardly say it "explains why the downvoters (-3 right now and it got downvoted fast) seem to be missing something". Compared to the the first revision you expanded the bold from "without having to specify" to "without having to specify them individually"  and reduced the bold from "one workplace" to "one".

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr

Why was that question downvoted in the first place? I am not sure why though.

@CPlus I have no idea.

@CPlus my guess: the bold text irritates people for some reason. But I added that so people would not just blow past that very relevant section of the text and vote to close because they thought it was already answered.

Bold text is not yelling, it's highlighting an important piece of text that the reader might easily miss.

I agree with your assessment of formatting. However, "remember the human" isn't important text in the edit you made to this Meta question. Instead, it's a backhanded way of accusing others of acting against policy, without understanding the relevant policy (either on the main space or on Meta). Nor is it necessary to emphasize "filter out that one workspace" in your question. Everyone already understood perfectly well what you wanted, which is why they didn't vote to close as unclear.

Side note: "My post is perfectly clear. You are all stupid." rarely goes over well even if it happens to be correct.

I really think the answer is that I didn't know the community was so against bold text. That's what started the whole thing, near as I can tell. No one has pointed to any sort of data on that topic, maybe it really is a consensus that I'm not aware of.

... I genuinely don't understand how you came to that conclusion. You were explicitly and repeatedly told many things here about what you did wrong that have nothing to do with bold text. Is there some reason to suppose that we don't mean any of that, and the problem is really just about the bold text? Despite the fact that we hold ourselves free to use it when explaining things to you? If I'm being perfectly honest, it comes across that you are going out of your way not to listen to what you are being told.


I made an edit that explains why the downvoters (-3 right now and it got downvoted fast) seem to be missing something.

First off: no, you did nothing of the sort. The text you added is as follows:

I have clearly explained why the docs and the existing answers don't actually answer my question, the downvoters are apparently not reading the question properly.

That doesn't explain why the downvoters seem to be missing something. It merely makes the claim that the downvoters are missing something. Except it's a bit ruder than that.
Second: your claim in this added text is also suspect. You didn't really explain why the existing answers don't actually answer your question. Again, you merely asserted that they don't:

The answers here do not cover my scenario.

That fails to explain how your scenario is substantively different from the one(s) considered in the other Q&A. To your credit, you do explain why, in your view, the documentation doesn't answer your question:

there's nothing in the docs about negating a filter.

However, you did get an answer clearly showing that the documentation indeed does explain this - by citing the specific relevant part (apparently, not where you were looking). (For reference: use the ! syntax, apparently.)
A question being answered by the documentation doesn't at all disqualify a question (and neither does the sheer ease of answering), but it does suggest that you'd benefit from showing a bit of humility.
Third: you didn't just make this edit and then come to Meta to ask about the rollback. You did this after getting in an extended rollback war over a different edit from someone else - that was clearly improving your post by removing noise.
Fourth, and most importantly: no, questions should never contain content like what you proposed to add there.
Rather, Meta is the right place for such complaints, not within the question itself - since this is not a discussion forum. You seem to be aware of this, since you brought this complaint here - please be more proactive when a dispute occurs. In my view, it should have occurred to you that running into someone else's stubbornness is a sign that you need to actually investigate the issue and check who's in the right. After all, you've been here for more than 15 years - since only a couple of months into the site's history - don't you feel a duty to set a good example?
Keep in mind that the purpose of questions here is to be the question part of a repository of information presented in Q&A format. It is, notably, not a space to argue or complain, not a place to discuss the site process or policy, and not a support ticket that you are filing in order to get the underlying problem solved.

There's an overall theme here - and it may be a hard pill to swallow: it's not about you. When you post a question here, you are contributing it to the site, so that the combination of the question and answer can benefit everyone (including, hopefully, many future visitors who find your question from a search engine). You have agreed, by using the site, to license that content both to Stack Exchange, Inc. and to the public. Among other things, that entails that the community has the right to edit your posts to improve them per our standards. Undoing changes that are clearly made in accordance with policy, is disruptive.

"However, you did get an answer clearly showing that you were incorrect in this." -- that answer was on a different page. Not knowing about something is not the same as being incorrect.

"That fails to explain how your scenario is substantively different" - then people should ask instead of just downvoting.

"then people should ask instead of just downvoting." no; that's part of the purpose of downvotes. They can be undone after you've improved the question.

but why would people come back to a question that they have downvoted to see if it's been improved?

@jcollum They could follow the post and hope for improvement. They might want to come back to undo the downvote once it gets better.

That's a good reason to anticipate such concerns (I agree that most people don't, in practice, although the site does offer the tooling Dharman mentioned). But more generally, I would advise you not to take downvotes so seriously.

I have literally never done that in my 15 years on this site, so it strikes me as unusual behavior.

The Gamification of Stack Overflow provides NO benefit to revisiting and reassessing a question, so yeah, you're generally stuck with any early downvotes you receive. Only reason I revisit posts for a few days after voting (up or down. I've seen some good questions totally ed over by edits) is to get the warm and fuzzy feeling of a job well done.

it's now at +5 -4, so it's actually got more downvotes and the original downvotes were not retracted afaics

It is absolutely inappropriate to add such metacommentary to a post as is explained in the other answer. However, it is also inappropriate everywhere else, including the comment section. You don't know why someone has downvoted a post. The downvoters most likely moved on and won't read the comment. People who cannot vote can judge for themselves how valid the current post score is if they don't trust it. So such comments are futile noise.
As an aside, including noise such as what you did, to your posts is likely to attract more downvotes.

Directly addressing downvoters does not belong to a question.
If you see how you can improve the post to make it better, such as adding missing details, or addressing ambiguities, or similar, then you should edit the post, but metacommentary does not belong there.
Edits you have been rolling back have improved your post. Please don't roll back such edits.

Removing bold text does not improve the post in my opinion -- and it is my post so I'll do what I want

@jcollum Please remember that Stack Overflow is a collaborative effort. Everyone else has as much right to edit the post as you do.

I find it rude to make trivial edits to someone else's post that reduce the readability of the text. Unless there's some survey of SO users about bold text that you can point to?

"and it is my post so I'll do what I want " this actually isn't true either. The terms you agree to hybusing the site, and the CC-by-SA licence the content is licenced under means that you can't just do anything to your post here on [so].

seems needlessly pedantic, I didn't think I'd have to say "I'll edit my post how I like (while staying within the site's rules)"

Well, no; the point is that editing it how you like apparently isn't within the site's rules - because the changes you want to make are clearly making the post worse, and because you've been disregarding the (fairly standard) reasoning behind the changes made by others.

I want to point out that the usage of the bold text is within reason and a stylistic choice. The author can consider adding that back if they really want to, and it's also not a big deal so it can stay as proposed by the editor.

The issue that I have overall here is: if no one tells me what's wrong with a post how will I know what to improve -- and if "bold is bad" is a community norm, how would I know that if the user making the edits doesn't tell me that? For all I know it's just one user who finds bold text annoying. Feedback is necessary for growth. Just editing my question to be what you like is not feedback. Just downvoting is not (constructive) feedback.

Bold is not bad! Downvotes are not meant as feedback to the author. If someone wants to offer feedback they can write a comment.  Voting is just content rating.

@Dharman Bold is not bad and can be used to emphasize some point. The problem arises when it is used too much and another more important one is when good edit as a whole is being rolled back, instead of tweaked to keep the parts that are undoubtfully good.

One vote is not feedback, many votes are a signal though. If a post receives a dozen+ downvotes, there is no reasonable argument to be made that they're all wrong. The content is Stack Overflow-incompatible. Problematic is that there is a very reduced chance that feedback will be provided to highlight what will be wrong with it, that process has derailed a lot over the years because you just can't know if a person is looking for feedback, or for someone to hate and target. Rather than walk through a mine field, people will generally just walk around it; path of least resistance.

"tweaked to keep the parts that are undoubtfully good" how would I know which parts were offending people if no one says anything, they just downvote?

@jcollum it's fairly easy to determine what parts of a ranty meta post are offensive to people if one has been here for a while.

I'm not talking about the Meta post.

the same argument applies, :shrug:

how can I determine what parts of a post people object to if no one says anything about it? A little communication goes a long way and if you are taking the time to make edits to a post twice it doesn't seem like much to ask

"how can I determine what parts of a post people object to if no one says anything about it? " By understanding the basics of policy (for example by reading the "how to ask", "how to produce a proper minimal reproducible example" etc. guidelines in the Help Center, taking the tour, and looking for guidance on Meta), and by applying common sense. For example: if someone edits your post, you should not need to be told that this expresses "the part I changed was suboptimal; it should be like what I changed it to, instead".

Similarly, again: it's not about you - therefore, think about what you would want the post to look like, if someone else had written it, then you found it with a search engine because you had the same problem. You would want to be able to verify, as quickly as possible, that it was indeed the same problem, right? You would not want to read the OP's previous back-and-forth figuring out the question, right? You would not want to see the OP arguing with the rest of the site about whether it's on topic or whether they missed something, right?

@jcollum You are assuming that person who made the edit also downvoted your post. This is wrong, because you don't know that, it is only a possibility. So when you received the edit, it is very likely that person who was editing never saw anything they think would warrant the comment. Additionally, they don't have to be a subject matter expert and they don't have to know whether some information is missing from your question so they could leave a comment about how you could improve your post.

Also, if you genuinely want a feedback, then rolling back edits and adding "the downvoters are apparently not reading the question properly" will definitely give signal to others to stay away or their actions can easily backfire and they can become targets for revenge voting. You have achieved the complete opposite of what you said you want.
